# How do i make a GET request in a coroutine?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mono

Working on a project for android... I can't get a request to be received by the server... I tried TcpSocket, TcpClient, WebClient and the others. But no, Unity seems to be stuck to 2008-era Mono (2.0.5.0).

I can't even reference UnityWebRequest...

How do I make a GET request with a coroutine?

Comment: `I can't even reference UnityWebRequest` why not?

Comment: it was not defined in the networking namespace so i guess it was an old version of the engine

Answer (score 0):

The lack of basic dotnet apis make this a really annoying task. WWW to the rescue!

```
public static IEnumerator downloadString(string apiUrl, Callback<WWW> callBack){
    WWW i = new WWW(apiUrl);
    while (!i.isDone) yield return i;
    callBack(w);        
    yield break;
}
```

Usage:

```
someObject.StartCoroutine(downloadString("http://192.168.1.5/x.php", (w)=>{
     DBG.Log(w.text); // do something
}));
```

Comment: `WWW` is obsolete, though and you should use [`UnityWebRequest.Get`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Get.html)

Comment: it seems that the project I was working with was built for an older version of unity...